# Using "." vs "->" in pointers and structures

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am confused as to when to use `.` vs. `->`.

I have seen both being used when referencing an item in a structure.

Here's an example:

```
typedef struct stack{
   int top;
   double numbers[100];
}stack;

stack the_stack;
the_stack.top = 0;
```

Would you use `->` if this was the following was the case:

```
typedef struct stack{
   int top;
   double numbers[100];
} *stack;

stack the_stack;
the_stack->top = 0;
```

If not, when is `.` used in C?

Comment: `->` are used when the calling object is a pointer, `.` is used when the calling object is an object or a reference (`&`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` operator is the **value membership operator**. This means that it is used when you are accessing the object's value.

The `->` operator is the **pointer membership operator**. The object before it is a pointer to a structure, and this goes into the pointer to access the object's members.

To use your example:

```
typedef struct stack {
   int top;
   double numbers[100];
} stack;
```

Then you could do any of these:

```
struct stack my_stack, *my_stack_pointer;
my_stack.top = 3;  // Change the value of stack.top
// From whatever my_stack_pointer points to, take the value of top, and
// assign 3 to it
(*my_stack_pointer).top = 3;
// Same idea as the previous, only abbreviated
my_stack_pointer->numbers[0] = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are both correct. `.` is used for a structure element while `->` is used for dereferencing a pointer to a structure.

In genera, `x->y` is the same as `(*x).y`. (The latter construct is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

`.` operator is used to when you have an `object` to the structure.
`->` is used when you have a `pointer` to the structure, you de-reference it and access the memory location.

But keep in mind you need to **allocate the memory first to de-reference your pointer**, in case of object, you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, really. `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`, that is, first dereference the pointer `a`, then access member `b`.

In C++, it is in theory possible to do different things with the two operators, but it's bad practice to do so (since it contrasts with everything people expect from the rest of C or C++).

Answer (score 0):

```
the_stack->top is only shorthand for (*the_stack).top.
```

whenever you have a `pointer to a structure`, you must dereference the pointer then access the elements in the structure, the arrow is a shortcut for doing `(*the_stack).top` replace this with the arrow now its much cleaner and nicer `the_stack->top`

Answer (score 0):

When u use pointer to a structure , '->' is used '.' otherwise.

```
typedef struct stack{
   int top;
   double numbers[100];
} *stack;

stack the_stack;
the_stack->top = 0; // equivalent to (*the_stack).top=0
```

Answer (score 0):

We use **.** for **object.attribute**.
    And **->** is just syntactic sugar for, **(*a).attribute = a->atribute**

This **->** is used mainly so the programmer by fault doesn't writes ***a.attribute**.